# Functional Interface Inheritance Quirk

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, default-method, functional-interface

I have a custom interface I've been using for some time that looks something like this:

```
public interface Function<T, R> {
    R call(T input);
}
```

I'd like to retrofit this interface with both Java's [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) as well as Guava's [`Function`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html), while keeping it a [`FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html). I thought I had the perfect arrangement:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function<T, R> extends
        java.util.function.Function<T, R>,
        com.google.common.base.Function<T, R> {

    R call(T input);

    @Override
    default R apply(T input) {
        return call(input);
    }
}
```

Both superinterfaces declare the same `apply()` method, which has been implemented in my interface, leaving only the abstract `call()` method. Strangely, it won't compile, telling me

> Invalid '@FunctionalInterface' annotation; Function<T,R> is not a functional interface

Stranger still, the following variations compile just fine:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function<T, R> extends
        java.util.function.Function<T, R> {

    R call(T input);

    @Override
    default R apply(T input) {
        return call(input);
    }
}
```

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function<T, R> extends
        com.google.common.base.Function<T, R> {

    R call(T input);

    @Override
    default R apply(T input) {
        return call(input);
    }
}
```

```
public interface Function<T, R> extends
        java.util.function.Function<T, R>,
        com.google.common.base.Function<T, R> {

    R call(T input);

    @Override
    default R apply(T input) {
        return call(input);
    }
}
```

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function<T, R> extends
        java.util.function.Function<T, R>,
        com.google.common.base.Function<T, R> {

    @Override
    R apply(T input);
}
```

Is there a reason the first version won't compile?

Comment: Your third one compiles because you haven't added the constraint that it must be a `@FunctionalInterface` (that's an annotation validated by the compiler).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, obviously.

Comment: Are you compiling with Eclipse? Compiles fine with Oracle's compiler.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, yes, I am using Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2).

Comment: This should compile and does compile with javac. Looks like an eclipse bug.... Also I'm not sure why you want to do that - the main point of functional interfaces is to create lambdas and the name of the method does not matter. So this lambda `a -> doSomething(a)` can be assigned to any of the 3 Functions interfaces...

Comment: @assylias, say I have a method that accepts my `Function` and I want to refactor it to accept any Java `Function`. Or say I have an instance of my `Function` that I want to be able to pass to a Guava method.

Comment: If this is an Eclipse bug, any suggestions as to how I can work around it?

Comment: @shmosel - workaround, IntelliJ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it compiles fine with the oracle compiler. 
It is an eclipse bug.

Awaiting for a bug fix, personally i will remove the annotation `@FunctionalInterface` (your 3rd variation):

```
public interface Function<T, R>
                                extends
                                    java.util.function.Function<T, R>,
                                    com.google.common.base.Function<T, R> {

    R call(T input);

    @Override
    default R apply(T input) {
        return call(input);
    }
}
```

The major inconvenient of this solution is that the eclipse compiler bug prevent  from using the `Function` as a [lambda target type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing).

---

If you really want to keep `@FunctionalInterface` on your `Function`, a (ugly) workaround might be to introduce an intermediate interface:

```
public interface AdapterFunction<T, R>
                                      extends
                                          java.util.function.Function<T, R>,
                                          com.google.common.base.Function<T, R> {
    @Override
    default R apply(T input) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and let your `Function` extends this `AdapterFunction`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function<T, R>
                                extends
                                    AdapterFunction<T, R> {

    R call(T input);

    @Override
    default R apply(T input) {
        return call(input);
    }
}
```

In this case, the `Function` is a valid target type for eclipse too:

```
Function<String, Object> function = st -> st.toString();
```

Comment: Yes, I found a similar bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=453552).

I don't care about the annotation itself; the problem is that it won't let me use lambda expressions.

I tried something similar your adapter idea, with no success. I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: The solution with the `AdapterFunction` works in eclipse too. But removing the `@FunctionalInterface` (3rd variation) don't

Comment: You're right, it works implement `apply()` in the adapter. Thanks!

Comment: "*The major inconvenient of this solution is that you couldn't use the Function as a lambda target type*" => Why not? You don't need an interface to be marked as `@FunctionalInterface` ot be used as a target type for a lambda, as long as it effectively is a functional interface...

Comment: @assylias you are theoretically right but in practice the eclipse compiler does  not accept it. It works only with the oracle compiler

Comment: @gontard Ah - I was not aware of the nth bug!

Comment: @assylias: obviously, Eclipse uses the same code to determine whether `@FunctionalInterface` can be applied and whether a lambda expression’s target type is a functional interface. Which makes sense. So you don’t need to have an `@FunctionalInterface` annotation, but you need a compiler with a correct test for functional interface compliance. I suspect, this version of Eclipse would reject that interface even with the annotation, as the presence of the annotation is not sufficient for the compiler.

Comment: @Holger - this bug must manifest itself in other ways too. I bet if we have an empty interface extending the two Functions, the interface will be counted as having two abstract methods too :)